# How to turn a EF Core/LINQ query into a List<SelectList>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have the following Category Model:

```
public class CategoryDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SelectList> WarehouseNames { get; set; }
}
```

Warehouse Model:

```
public class Warehouse
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Location { get; set; }
public int MaxCapacity { get; set; }   
}
```

I want to get all the Warehouse.Id and Warehouse.Name in my database and store them in the CategoryDTO.WarehouseNames (value: Id, Text: Name) so I can display them in a dropdown list. Does anybody know how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

fix Dto to List, and maybe you need to add a WarehouseId too???

```
public class CategoryDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int WarehouseId { get; set; } //????
    public List<SelectListItem> WarehouseNames { get; set; }
}
```

in you action should be  something like this

```
var model= new CategoryDTO();

var wareHouseNames = context.Set<Warehouse>()
                    .Select ( i=>  new SelectListItem {
                     Text = i.Name,
                     Value = i.Id
                    }).ToList();
model.WareHouseNames = wareHouseNames ;

return View(model)
```

and view

```
@model CategoryDTO


<select class="form-control"  asp-for="@WarehouseId" asp-items="@WareHouseNames">
         <option value="0" >Select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think you may have `Text` and `Value` backwards?

Comment: @NetMage  Yes, you  are right.  I just fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make the "public List" into  Dictionary and use the key as Id and value as Name from "WareHouse" object.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to remove the `WarehouseNames` property from the `CategoryDTO` type completely, and instead of populating one `CategoryDTO` object populate a `List<CategoryDTO>` or (even better!) `IEnumerable<CategoryDTO>`.

Then you will be able to map these CategoryDTO items to a dropdown list/HTML `Select` entity. Exactly what that looks like, though, depends on information not yet in your question.

Comment: I think the OP wants to display the `WarehouseNames` in a dropdown list, not the `CategoryDTO`s.

Comment: Yes, I need to display the WarehouseNames